# extjs 5, deine dropzone on gridpanel, but cannot drop, why?

Tags: javascript, extjs, drag-and-drop, gridpanel

I want to drag a pic and drop to gridpanel.
I definde a gridpanel and code is below,

```
viewConfig: {
    listeners: {
        render: 'onPlaylistgridviewRender'
    }
},

onPlaylistgridviewRender: function(component, eOpts) {
    var gridView = component,
        grid = gridView.up('playlistgridpanel');

    grid.dropZone = Ext.create('Ext.dd.DropZone', component.el, {
        notifyDrop: function(source, e, data){
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I drag a pic , when mouse is over the grid, this icon shows dropping  is forbidden.

what's wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both dragged picture and the drop target (the grid) must be in the [ddGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.dd.DropZone-cfg-ddGroup).

Comment: I  see sample in `ext-5.0.1/build/examples/dd/dragdropzones.js` and it seems it does not use ddGroup. I just want insert  a record into grid when dropping, that sample seems to be more complex. Coud you give me   a sample?